# Selecting from a list then searching to select more

Tags: tables, selection, multi-selection

I have a list that goes into pages. we allow the user to select from the list to preform some actions on the selected items.
i have a problem covering the following scenario

1. select 3 items from the first page.
2. filtering the list with parameter X ( the first 3 selected items doesnt have this X parameter )
3. select all the items after applying the filter

The problem now its not communicated that the selection is ( 3 itmes + all the itmes with parameter x )

How to communicate this? or should i prevent this behaviour?

Comment: You should provide more context on this.

Comment: show us some mocks of your efforts so far; this will make the question more valuable for others sharing a similar context.